# Not able to INSERT data at my choice into go-sqlmock command

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

Trying to execute an api-test, test calls a mysql gorm `SELECT` command, then subsequently executes an `INSERT` command, the `SELECT` command works, but I have not been able to insert data at my choice into the `INSERT` command, however the `INSERT` command works if I try not to `INSERT any data at my choice.

```
func Test_CreateProject(t *testing.T) {
   db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
   if err != nil {
      t.Fatalf("an error '%s' was not expected when opening a stub database connection", err)
   }
   defer db.Close()

   gormDB, err := gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{
      Conn: db,
      SkipInitializeWithVersion: true,
   }), &gorm.Config{})
   if err != nil {
      panic(err) // Error here
   }

   var (
      userID             = uint(1)
      userName           = "Jon"
      userUsername       = "johnny"
      userEmail          = "email@email.com"
      userAdministrator  = true
   )

   mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT(.*)").
      WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"id", "name", "username", "email", "administrator"}).
      AddRow(userID, userName, userUsername, userEmail, userAdministrator))

   // insert
   mock.ExpectBegin()
   mock.ExpectExec("INSERT INTO projects\\(name, description\\)").
      WithArgs("name", "description").
      WillReturnResult(&result{insertID:int64(1),rowsAffected:int64(1)})
   fmt.Println(mock.ExpectationsWereMet())
   mock.ExpectCommit()

   r := mux.NewRouter()
   r.HandleFunc("/project", CreateProject(gormDB)).Methods("POST")
   ts := httptest.NewServer(r)
   defer ts.Close()
   apitest.New().
      Debug().
      Handler(r).
      Post("/project").
      //Body(fmt.Sprintf(`{"name": "%s", "description": %s}`, name, description)).
      Expect(t).
      //Body(`{"CreatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","UpdatedAt":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","DeletedAt":null,"ID":1,"name":"Valshlid","description":"Rand byggður kassi við Hlidarenda i RVK"}`).
      Status(http.StatusOK).
      End()
}
```

```
func (project *Project) CreateProject(db *gorm.DB) *error.ErrorResp {
    if err := db.Create(&project).Error; err != nil {
        errResponse := error.New(error.WithDetails(err))
        return errResponse
    }

    return nil
}
```

```
mysql> desc projects;
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at  | datetime(3)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime(3)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at  | datetime(3)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(191)    | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| description | longtext        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
ExecQuery: could not match actual sql: "INSERT INTO `projects` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)" with expected regexp "INSERT INTO projects\(name, description\)"; call to Rollback transaction, was not expected, next expectation is: %!s(PANIC=String method: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)
[0.098ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO `projects` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`description`) VALUES ('2022-11-05 10:30:34.37','2022-11-05 10:30:34.37',NULL,'','')

<---------- final response
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"Err":{"code":500,"status":"Internal Server Error","message":"","details":["ExecQuery: could not match actual sql: \"INSERT INTO `projects` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`description`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)\" with expected regexp \"INSERT INTO projects\\(name, description\\)\"; call to Rollback transaction, was not expected, next expectation is: %!s(PANIC=String method: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)"]}}

    assert.go:105:
            Error Trace:    assert.go:259
                                        assert.go:89
                                        assert.go:78
                                        apitest.go:1043
                                        apitest.go:880
                                        apitest.go:687
                                        projectcontroller_test.go:206
            Error:          Not equal:
                            expected: 200
                            actual  : 500
            Test:           Test_CreateProject
Duration: 961.959µs

--- FAIL: Test_CreateProject (0.00s)
FAIL
FAIL    timeclock/controllers   0.205s
FAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using "mock.ExpectPrepare" instead of "mock.ExpectExec".
Not sure you have tried that?

Comment: Did you check this option? Please review and update.